# Modify form action in a form listener

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.5

I have a form listener as defined below

```
class GenerateFormActionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if ($data || null !== $data->getId()) {
        $form->getConfig()->setAction('a_route_to_be_generated');
        }
    }
}
```

The event is triggered correctly and I got this error

> The config builder cannot be modified anymore.

I need to generate routes depending on entity data.
Any advice how to modify the action ? (when ? It appears to be too late cause the config is locked)

Comment: You could do it in your controller or do it in your template or do it in a `Twig_Extension` that will generate it in your template.

Comment: You are right but soon I'll add more business logic so I'd like to keep my controller and twig as skinny as possible.

Comment: So you could create a service that generated the path, which you call in the `Twig_Extension` meaning you only use something like `generate_path(object)` in your template. This way the business logic is all inside a service so it's available everywhere and your template and controller stays (relatively) untouched.